# Is there a way to define custom legend in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a chart which internally is built using multiple highcharts.I want to create a custom legend for whole chart. Is there a way to show custom legend. Is yes then can someone point me to some example.

Comment: what means multiple highcharts? Do you have one Highcharts object or many? Or you have things similar to that one? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

Comment: Yes you can, and then catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) on chart (with enabled legend). Then call [series.hide() / show()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show) in other charts.

Comment: One div area contains many highcharts..want to show one legend for all those charts.

Comment: How about my suggestion?

Comment: @sebastian Thanks for your suggestion. But can u point to some example how to draw custom legend,

Comment: let me know what you have tried and how your charts looks like? Could you prepare your chart on jsfiddle.net ?